# numpy frombuffer() and tostring() - reading from csv

Tags: python, numpy

I have been at this for hours, looking all over SO without a decent answer to my specific problem.

So, I'm building a training set for a reinforcement learning model, and I'd like to save that training set to a csv file. Each record of the training set is of the form,

```
[np.ndarray(shape=(18,8,8)), np.ndarray(shape=(1968,)), int64]
```

The input to a neural network is an 18x8x8 tensor/numpy array, and the output is a flat-array (1968) policy + an integer value.

When I go to write this to a `csv` file, I use the following numpy function on the input and policy elements of each record:

```py
    input_bytes = inputs.tobytes() # inputs.tostring() also works
    policy_bytes = policy.tobytes() # same here, policy.tostring()
```

When it comes training time, I need to read these columns from the csv file, and **turn the bytes back into** `numpy.ndarray` objects. I know the original datatypes and shapes - `np.int32`, `(18,8,8)` for the input and `np.float64`, `(1968,)` for the policy. So, you'd think I could simply use:

```py
    # need to use *_bytes[1:] because the 'b' character is written
    # to the csv when we save
    inputs = np.reshape(np.fromstring(input_bytes[1:], dtype=np.int32), (18,8,8))
    policy = np.fromstring(policy_bytes[1:], dtype=np.float64)
```

This fails, giving the error:

```
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

If I try and convert the string to bytes, and use `frombuffer`, i.e.

```py
    inputs = np.reshape(np.frombuffer(bytes(input_bytes[1:], 'utf-8'), dtype=np.int32), (18,8,8))
    policy = np.frombuffer(bytes(policy_bytes[1:], 'utf-8'), dtype=np.float64)
```

I get essentially the exact same error.

```
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

I realize that this must be some sort of encoding issue, but I can't exactly pinpoint it. Note that the following works perfectly:

```
test_input = np.zeros(shape=(18,8,8), dtype=np.int32).tobytes()
test_policy = np.zeros(shape=(1968,), dtype=np.float64).tobytes()

np.reshape(np.frombuffer(test_input, dtype=np.int32), (18,8,8))
np.frombuffer(test_policy, dtype=np.float64)
```

**How can I write the bytes to a `csv` file, and load them back into a ndarray object at a later time via reading from the file?**

EDIT: Here's an example of the csv:

[image: csv head]

Comment: Show a sample of the csv.

Comment: Uploaded the head of the csv file. Let me know if you need any other info! thank you

Comment: How did you write these bytestrings to the text file?  The `b'....'` wrapper makes using those strings unnecessarily complicated.  That's a Py3 unicode display of a bytestring.  But a bigger question, why `csv` or text file for a 3 or 4d array?  Why not `npy` or `pickle`?

Comment: It might also help to know how (exactly) you read the csv.  I don't see a `loadtxt`, so maybe you are doing you own line read and split.

Comment: Show `input_bytes` (or at least part).  I get something like `"b'\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\...x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\t'"`

Comment: Here's my `input_bytes`:

`b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\...\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

I am actually loading the `csv` via `pandas.read_csv` and probably should have made that explicitly clear... I eventually use pandas downstream to do some other processing, but not during any part of this.

I will probably try npy or pickle, yeah I didn't think of that. I just immediately landed on csv.

Edit: my `input_bytes` is *before* writing to csv. After is obviously what's in the image. Looks the same, but yes the `b''` wrapper is killing me.

Comment: I just want to say sorry for wasting time - I have no idea why I implanted this idea of using `csv` so deep in my head - `.npy` is working perfectly in 2 lines of code.

But this seems like it's something that should be doable, in some rare use case.